# Can I Approximate a Homeomorphism by Permuting a Grid?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $f: [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]^2$ be a homeomorphism of the square. By the *n-grid* I mean the collection of smaller squares $$[a/2^n,a/2^n + 1/2^n] \times [b/2^n,b/2^n + 1/2^n] \text{ for } a,b = 0,\ldots, 2^{n}-1$$ for some natural number $n$. I would like to take some grid fine enough that $f$ can be approximated by permuting the grid elements.

Formally, let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Does there exist an $n$-grid and permutation $\sigma$ of the squares in the grid such that for each $x \in [0,1]^2$ we have $d(f(x),\sigma (A)) < \epsilon$ for every grid element $A$ with $x \in A$?

This looks a little like simplicial approximation but I can't find anything about simplicial approximations of homeomorphisms being bijective.

Comment: I think my edit was better than the one you just made, since there's only one grid element $A$ containing $x$.

Comment: The grid elements overlap at the boundaries. The corners are elements of up to four of the small squares.

Comment: One natural approach is to, for a large $n$, form a bipartite graph, with each vertex set being $\{Q_{a,b}\}$ the collection of cubes in the $n$-grid, and connect $Q_{a,b}$ to $Q_{a',b'}$ iff there is some $x \in Q_{a,b}$ with $f(x) \in Q_{a',b'}$. By uniform continuity, if there is a perfect matching, we would be done. However, it may very well be the case that multiple cubes map into the same cube...

Comment: Tricky, isn't it?

Comment: Since the domain is compact $f$ being bijective and continuous implies it's a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{100}$. Take any homeomorphism mapping $[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[\frac{1}{2},1]$ into $[0,\frac{1}{2^{10}}]\times[1-\frac{1}{2^{10}},1]$. For $n=1$, we must send $[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[\frac{1}{2},1]$ to itself, and so the inverse of the point $(\frac{1}{2^9},1-\frac{1}{2^9})$ (say) must be far from its corresponding cube. And for any $n \ge 2$, some cubes in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[\frac{1}{2},1]$ will be sent far away from $[0,\frac{1}{2^{10}}]\times[1-\frac{1}{2^{10}},1]$.

Comment: This answer looks good. Looks like I need to change the question.

Comment: Here is the harder question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322050/can-i-approximate-a-homeomorphism-by-permuting-a-non-uniform-grid