# Can I approximate a Homeomorphism by Permuting a (non uniform) grid?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320884/can-i-approximate-a-homeomorphism-by-permuting-a-grid?noredirect=1#comment6832983_3320884).

Let $f: [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]^2$ be a homeomorphism of the unit square. By a *nonuniform $n$-grid* I mean a collection of smaller squares with corners of the form $a/2^n$ for $a = 0,1,\ldots, 2^{n}$ such that

1. The smaller squares cover the unit square
2. The smaller squares intersect only along their edges

I would like to take two nonuniform grids fine enough that $f$ can be approximated by swapping the grid elements

Formally, let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Does there exist some $n \in \mathbb N$ and nonuniform $n$-grids $F,G$ and bijection $\sigma:G \to F$  such that for each $x \in [0,1]^2$ we have $d(f(x),y) < \epsilon$ for every grid element $A$ with $x \in A$ and $y \in \sigma(A)$?

**Edit:** This used to read: "$d(f(x),\sigma(A)) < \epsilon$ for every grid element $A$ with $x \in A$" which can be ensured by taking a single grid element.

This looks a little like simplicial approximation but I can't find anything about simplicial approximations of homeomorphisms being bijective.

Comment: Is such a result known in the simpler case of a homeomorphism of the unit interval?

I am struggling to prove it for the example $[0,1] \to [0,1]$, $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the result has a well-known name. You should be able to do it for the interval just by breaking up the domain into small pieces to define $G$. Then define $F$ as the image of the elements of $G$. This works since the map is monotone so the images of the "squares" are again "squares". Use uniform continuity to decide how fine $G$ has to be.

Comment: If you can prove this for the interval, where is the difficulty for the square? Shouldn't the proof go through essentially the same?

Comment: But @Daron, I thought you were asking about permuting the squares/intervals (in which case you are approximating a interval homeomorphism by **Interval Exchange Maps** (I.E.T.'s).

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I understand or not.

If one of your grids is obtained by rearranging the squares of another, I believe my lower dimensional point holds. Otherwise, you're absolutely right!

Comment: @Daron why can't you take $F=G=\{[0,1]^2\}$?

Comment: @Ben I think the question is unambiguous and clearly written. $F$ and $G$ can be different non-uniform $n$-grids. $\sigma$ is just a set-theoretic bijection between them. (If $F$ and $G$ had to be the same, why not just call them both $F$?)

Comment: @mthworker. You're right. I have changed the question to make more sense of "approximating" the map. We want the image of the square to be very close around the image of $x$.

Comment: @quarague: The proof is straightforward for monotone maps on the interval, because those maps turn one grid into another. For more general maps the images can overlap in bad ways.

Comment: @Daron I'm not convinced the example in my answer to the previous version of this question will even work for this question. I'll think more.

Comment: I'm not sue either. I am trying to change the hyptheses to rule out examples like yours!

Comment: @Daron Hi Daron. Are you still interested in this question? Did you see if the answer to the previous version of this question works for this question?

Comment: Hi Mathworker: I managed to find another way to do what I wanted.

Comment: @Daron you should do @ my name. I didn't get a notification for your message. Maybe delete this question?